Can I send Thanos data directly to Telegraf/InfluxDB?
From what I understand,

Prometheus can write data to a Thanos instance

and Prometheus can, using its remote write protocol, write data to a Telegraf instance, which then pipes it to an associated InfluxDB instance


If, however, I do not have access to the base Prometheus instance, can I pull data from the Thanos instance to my Telegraf/InfluxDB instance? And if so, how?
What I've found is that it is possible to iterate over a list of Thanos queries and collate the results in JSON format, but doing so requires a list of all valid queries for the given Thanos dataset, and to compile that list I had to manually go through the Thanos GUI to find every valid query, so I'd much rather an automated method - either an automated way to run every valid query, or a method that doesn't involve the Thanos Query API at all and instead sends the data direct to Telegraf/Influx without needing to go via plaintext.
